# ls -lR doesnt works when run through script

Tags: bash, ls

When I run the command from prompt it gives the result but when i script it it says ls cannot access.Below is my script

```
for server in $(echo $prod_daemon | sed "s/,/ /g")
    do
            echo "********$server PROD collecting the files*********"
                                    ssh -TAtt ubuntu@18.221.144.194 ssh -A -o ConnectTimeout=5 -o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@$server "find /lunera/code/*/current/ -type f -print0 |xargs -0 ls -lR -1 | awk '"'"'{print $5"\t\t"$9}'"'"'|sort -n|awk 'NF' " >daemon0$a
```

Please help

Comment: `ls` [shouldn't be used in scripts in the first place](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: If you *did* want to track down exactly where your original code is going wrong (which I don't much recommend, because trying to build correct double-escaped code is painful), put a `set -x;` in front of the `find` command to enable trace logging.

Answer (score 1):

If, as I try to follow this, you're trying to find the largest file (within your search locations) on each server, it's more sensible to use `ssh -o ProxyCommand` than to nest two separate `ssh` invocations manually, and it makes more sense to use `find -printf` than to invoke `ls` at all.

Thus:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IFS=, read -r -a servers <<<"$prod_daemon"

for server in "${servers[@]}"; do
  echo "********$server PROD collecting the files*********"
  ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh ubuntu@18.221.144.194 nc -w 10 %h %p" \
      -o ConnectTimeout=5 \
      -o BatchMode=yes \
      -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
      "ubuntu@$server" 'bash -s' >"$server.largefile.txt" <<'____EOF'
    find /lunera/code/*/current/ -type f -printf '%s\t%p\0' |
      sort -zn |
      tail -z -n 1 |
      { IFS= read -r -d $'\t' size; IFS= read -r -d '' filename;
        printf 'Largest file is: %q\n' "$filename"; }
____EOF
done
```

Comment: This is not showing absolute path of the file . Inned the absolute path and recursively also

Comment: `find` *is* recursive unless that's explicitly turned off (as with `-maxdepth 1`). And getting the absolute path only requires changing `%P` to `%p`.